# Hibernate Annotation to map a referenced column

Tags: java, hibernate

In my entity, i have a Player object mapped as following

```
@JoinColumn(name = "player_id", referencedColumnName = "player_id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Player player;
```

But now if i need to access the id of the player I need to go though the player object. Instead of that is there a way to  map the referenced column directly to the entity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get the player id without loading the object then you can do the following.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "player_id", referencedColumnName = "player_id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Player player;

@Column(name="player_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Long playerId;
```

Since the column `player_id` is a repeated mapping it has to be marked as read-only (as above).